# iOS CoreBluetooth and preventing other devices to connect to your peripheral

Tags: ios, bluetooth, uuid, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral

I am creating a core bluetooth application and connecting to a peripheral device, is there a way for the peripheral to reject which centrals may connect to it? What if a random person scanned and found my peripheral devices broadcasted UUID and then broadcasted that UUID and tried to connect to it, how would I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

No, the iOS peripheral cannot prohibit centrals from connecting to it. However it has some tricks to disable the connection. When a dynamic characteristic is read:

1. return an error instead of the value of the characteristic,
2. don't respond to the request. This will cause the connection to stall and then break up after about 30 seconds.

Think of the advertisement as a real advertisement in the media. As many can see it as want. This is the same for iBeacons. You shouldn't rely any security on being hidden. (Wifi SSID broadcasting can be turned off but if your hotspot is not encrypted and authenticated, people with find you.)